# _com_ptr_t assignment in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have the following code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Initialize COM.
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

    // Create the interface pointer.
    ICalculatorPtr pICalc(__uuidof(ManagedClass));

    long lResult = 0;

    // Call the Add method.
    pICalc->Add(5, 10, &lResult);

    wprintf(L"The result is %d\n", lResult);


    // Uninitialize COM.
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

I want to first declare `pICalc` as a global variable and later assign some value inside the `_tmain` function. How can I do that? I suppose, like this:

```
ICalculatorPtr pICalc;
//...
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //...
    pICalc = __uuidof(ManagedClass);
}
```

But this throws:

> error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const _GUID' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Thanks in advance.

**Solution:**

```
ICalculatorPtr pICalc = NULL;
//...
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //...
    pICalc = new ICalculatorPtr(__uuidof(ManagedClass));
}
```

Comment: What happens if you just do that?

Comment: @JustSid Oh, yes, I forgot to put that. Edited!

Comment: You want `ICalculator* pICalc = NULL;` and then `pICalc = new ICalculator(__uidof(...`

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That works! Sorry, I'm new to C++ and VC++. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your suggested solution leaks memory. Make it

```
ICalculatorPtr pICalc;
pICalc.CreateInstance(__uuidof(ManagedClass));
```