# Cast a _com_ptr_t to void * and then back to _com_ptr_

Tags: visual-c++, com-interop

How do you cast a COM interface pointer to void pointer and then back to the COM pointer? Here is some code to illustrate my problem. It's very similar to this sample code: [_com_ptr_t assignment in VC++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849884/com-ptr-t-assignment-in-vc)

```
CoInitialize(NULL);

COMLib::ICalcPtr pCalc = COMLib::ICalcPtr("MyLibrary.Calculator");

pCalc->doSomething();

CoUninitialize();
return 0;
```

Now, if I were to cast the `pCalc` object to `void*`, how would I cast it back to `COMLib::ICalcPtr`? For example, the second line in the following code gives me a compile error *'QueryInterface' : is not a member of 'System::Void'*. Obviously, it's trying to call `IUknown.QueryInterface()` on the object. Preferably I would like to do this without creating a new interface (hence, without implicitly calling `QueryInterface` and `AddRef`).

```
void *test = pCalc;
COMLib::ICalcPtr pCalc2 = test;//'QueryInterface' : is not a member of 'System::Void'
```

FYI, the reason I'm doing this is that the object is going to be passed around from java to jni VC++ code as a `void*` type. I'm open to any suggestion on what to do or what is going on behind the scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same way you pass any other opaque structure that either doesn't fit in a pointer or doesn't convert easily: by passing its address.

```
void* test = new COMLib::ICalcPtr(pCalc);
```

...

```
COMLib::ICalcPtr pCalc2 = *(COMLib::ICalcPtr*)test;
delete (COMLib::ICalcPtr*)test;
```

This will result in calls to `AddRef` and `Release`, but not `QueryInterface`.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I get an exception Access Violation (0xC0000005) during casting and de-referencing. The best I could come up with is `COMLib::ICalcPtr pCalc2 = static_cast<IUnknown*>(test);` But that calls QueryInterface(). My thought was that since i've already created a smart pointer, why do I have to create another one?

Comment: I was doing something wrong, your answer is correct. However, in order to use the same smart pointer I did `COMLib::ICalcPtr *pCalc2 = static_cast<COMLib::ICalcPtr*>(test);` I'm not sure which is better in terms of best practice or performance.

Comment: @user845279: I made a new one simply because I didn't know how long your `pCalc` would remain alive.